# How can I run a PowerShell script after reboot?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that tails specifics logs. If there is no update to the logs within a specific time span, an alert is then sent to nagios (as this depicts that the service is no longer running).

The powershell script works great when run manually, but my issue is that I want it to load up on reboot. I've tried creating a scheduled task that repeats itself every 5 minutes using the arguments '-noexit -file C::\script.ps1'. The problem is then that my script doesn't actually work when run as a scheduled task.

The execution policy is set to Unrestricted, so the script runs, but the code doesn't execute and work like it does when manually run.

FWIW, the code is:

```
function Write-EventlogCustom($msg) {
    Write-EventLog System -source System -eventid 12345 -message $msg
}

Get-Content -Path C:\test.log -Wait | % {Write-EventlogCustom $_}
```

So if I update test.log while the powershell script runs a scheduled task, the event log doesn't get updated. However, when I run this script manually, and update to test.log, it does appear in the event viewer.

I'm hoping that a second set of eyes might find something that I may have missed?

Comment: Could you run it as a logon script, or starup script?

Comment: How do you have the permissions of the scheduled task configured? I believe Write-EventLog is going to need elevated permissions. Can you configure it to run as system? You might also put something simple in your script like "test" | Out-File "C:\test.txt" to see if the script is actually running.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the task scheduler needed to 'Run with highest privileges for it to work. I checked the box, and it's running well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim Ferrill has mentioned, I needed to run the process with task schedulers 'Run with highest privileges' setting. This resolved the issue.